# Redux persistReducer in React Native causing extremely slow reaction times

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

When using redux-persist v6 in React Native, it causes click events and animations to go extremely slow. Tapping a button takes about 5 or 6 seconds before it performs the action. In the `configureStore.ts` if I change createStore() to take `rootReducer` instead of `persistedReducer` (and also comment out the PersistGate in index.tsx) then the app responsiveness speeds up again. (FYI, the rest of the app uses `react-navigation` with `react-natigation-stack`.)

Does anyone have any recommendations to get the app to respond quickly even while using reduxPersist?

index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store, persistor } from './store/configureStore';
import { AppRegistry, View } from 'react-native';
import { MainNavigator } from './navigation/navigation';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'
import { appId } from './config';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store} >
      <PersistGate
        loading={<View style={{ backgroundColor: '#ffc900' }} />}
        persistor={persistor}>
        <MainNavigator />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  )
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appId, () => App);
```

configureStore.ts

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import { rootReducer } from '../reducer/rootReducer';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

let store = createStore(
  persistedReducer, // rootReducer,
  {},
  compose(applyMiddleware(thunk))
)

let persistor = persistStore(store)

export { store, persistor }
```

Comment: Is your state big? Are you using selectors?

Comment: I am experiencing the exact same thing! I have a very large state, but i'm careful with my selectors - did you find a fix?

Comment: It seems this is related to `timeout` option in `persistReducer`. https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/issues/816